# Android Proxy Settings

Tags: android, proxy

Does every app use the value defined in the [Settings.System.HTTP_PROXY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#HTTP_PROXY) or just the web browser?

Answer (score 2):

For Android devices with API version >= 11 (3.x or greater), the developers should use the following procedure to get the current proxy settings:

```
ProxySelector defaultProxySelector = ProxySelector.getDefault();
List<Proxy> proxyList = defaultProxySelector.select("http://www.google.it");
```

It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446871/how-users-developers-can-set-the-androids-proxy-configuration-for-versions-2-x).

On devices with API version < 11, there isn't an **official** support, so we *officially have a problem*. But stay tuned [here](http://www.android-proxy.com/), I'm trying to find out a solution also for older and forgotten (by Google) devices.