# App installed on Motorola RAZR Android (version 2.3.6) device in not going thru proxy

Tags: android, http, proxy

I'm seeing a weird issue with setting up a wifi proxy in Motorola Razr with android version 2.3.6. I'm able to set the wifi proxy properly. I've tested it by running browser from phone and seeing data passing by the proxy debugging tool (charles). But when I fire up the app, requests doesn't flow thru charles anymore. 
Do you have any idea, why apps behave differently than browser?

Thanks.

Comment: BTW: how can you set the proxy into the Motorola Razr? Does it have a per Access Point proxy setting or just only one proxy settings for every AP?

Comment: In Motorola razr, you can set proxy while adding a new SSID. Details are here: http://www.myvusers.com/forums/motorola-droid-razr/9772-set-up-wifi-connection-droid-razr-motorola.html

Comment: Oh nice. Didn't know about that! The stock Android 2.x ROM doesn't have this feature, so I don't know how Motorola implemented (maybe backporting from 3.1 but it's a guess).

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Every app developer should use the proxy if it's set. But sometimes they don't.

Comment: Agree. How can a developer use the existing proxy in his/her app? I'm assuming this proxy is global (set using "Settings" -> "wireless & networks" -> "Wifi Settings" -> "Add wifi-network" -> Enable proxy settings in this dialog)

Comment: I just asked the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446871/how-users-developers-can-set-the-androids-proxy-configuration-for-versions-2-x. Stressing a lot of googlers they promise me to give me an answer. We'll see.