# Android: how to set system wide properties

Tags: android, properties, proxy, settings, system

Starting from this [official statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693622/355465) that all xyAndroid versions previous API 11 doesn't support the `java.net.ProSelector` way to get the current proxy configuration, I would like to know if it's possible to transparently change in some way the properties that the ProxySelector class uses to store the proxy (If I'm not wrong, the ProxySelector implementation could be something like [these](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-libcore/java/net/ProxySelectorImpl.java.htm)).

The properties should be changed system wide, in order that all the 3rd party applications can access the current proxy configuration using the `java.net.ProxySelector` class.

Is it possible?

I'm trying to work on a [OSS library](http://code.google.com/p/android-proxy-library/) so that every user with "not so much" old devices can finally set the proxy for all the well written applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Android app runs it its own VM, so you won't be able to set system properties that span across all applications.

This is by design. Android apps are sand boxed. No one should be able to install an app that interferes with how my app connects to the network. Imagine if a rogue app could force all HTTP traffic through their proxy, and suck up all your user names and passwords.

If you want to affect network at an OS-wide level, you'll need to get into the Android platform source code. You can't do it as an application.

Comment: yes I know sandboxing, but I found [this article](http://rxwen.blogspot.it/2010/01/android-property-system.html) that seems to say that is possible, but I've some problems working out with NDK :( ..

Comment: @LeChuckCaptain : did you have any luck with NDK?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman: didn't have the time to spend on the project in last months.. I'll keep you updated!