# How opera mini can set the proxy

Tags: java, android, proxy, system, opera

It is just what the title said. I dont get it how does the opera can set the proxy by using opera:config. I want to achieve the same thing. Making my apps can set the proxy and then set the url that i want. What opera uses to change the proxy in android? i know that its deprecated with webview. And all i know is, you have to root and change your iptables. But how does the opera achieve it? That i dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that Opera is using a standard WebView?

Comment: I dont know for that. all i know is that proxy setting in webview are all deprecated D:

Comment: Yes, because you shouldn't set the proxy for the WebView, but just trust that the WebView get the right proxy settings from the System.

Comment: i know that, but my boss doesn't care about it. he's just thinking "your job must be done". Anyway i still can make it. now it works for ICS. but in JB and GB didnt work. i'll try to make it in JB. Or do you have any hint for that? btw thanks for your response. i'll accept the answer.

Comment: For what I remember I found a solution for ICS, but not for JB. After discussing with a Googler ([See here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9693622/355465)) I decided to give up trying to find this kind of solution. In JB they also removed the hidden activity for the Global proxy settings. I think they are trying to clean up things.

Comment: thanks i already make my apps that work with gb,ics, and jb 4.1.2, but it still using hardcode to insert username and password. and i hve another request to make it not using hardcode and let the user whether they wanna use proxy or not. yeah i hate that why they wanna cleaning up that function for newer android OS.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, can you paste a short piece of code to show your solution? Maybe I can add it to [APL](https://github.com/shouldit/android-proxy-library)!